# How to grep for hex patterns from within a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, hex

Thanks to this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695609/how-to-grep-for-presence-of-specific-hex-bytes-in-files

I've determined that I can grep for a particular hex pattern in a file and return the offset from bash like this:

```
$ time grep -obUaP -m1 "\xFF\xFF\x00\x01\x00\x01\x04\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" file.bin
1440710656:��

real    0m0.553s
user    0m0.452s
sys     0m0.101s
```

However, I'm trying to include this in a script.  When running that exact command from within a bash *script*, it fails:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

time grep -obUaP -m1 "\xFF\xFF\x00\x01\x00\x01\x04\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" file.bin

$ ./script.sh

real    0m20.888s
user    0m20.505s
sys     0m0.378s
```

I've tried using single quotes for the pattern, no quotes, storing in a variable, etc., but I can't figure out how to make that work.  I'm at a loss for why it won't work to begin with, so I'm not sure what exactly I should be troubleshooting.

Any suggestions for what I'm missing?

Comment: If the script consists of that command and nothing else, I am really surprised that the script takes 40 times as long and is using the CPU all the time. I have the feeling that the command in the script is not the same as the command line version. Is this the same `file.bin`?

Comment: It is.  file.bin is about 2 GB.  The direct grep finishes quickly because it stops processing after the first match.  The grep in the script never matches, so it keeps searching through all 2 GB.

Comment: That explanation makes sense, but unfortunately I have no solution for you.

Comment: Are there different locales in play in the script versus your interactive shell? Do you get a different result if you run `... LC_CTYPE=POSIX grep ...` ?

Comment: Yes!  That was the problem.  I can't remember exactly what made me set this in the past, but I have the following alias set in my shell: "alias grep='LANG=C grep --color'", which your comment reminded me of.  That was applied to my shell command, but not in the script.  If I add either that or your LC_CTYPE suggestion to the script, it works as expected.  Thanks!  Mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?